# how can I remove the primary key value from Asp.net mvc2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I wrote a method like as below:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "ProductID")]Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Products.AddObject(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

After successfully Creation of Create.aspx Page in mvc2.

I Run the application, After that if i click on Create New Link

it will open create.aspx with Id also.

How can i remove the ID from My Page.

Get Method is:

public ActionResult Create()

```
    {

        return View();

    }
```

My HTML Page is like below:

### Create

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">

            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductID) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">

            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductID) %>

            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductID) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">

            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">

            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductName) %>

            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">

            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cost) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">

            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost) %>

            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">

            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity) %>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">

            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity) %>

            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity) %>

        </div>

        <p>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />

        </p>

    </fieldset>


<% } %>

<div>

    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>

</div>
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can we see the get method for Create?

Comment: show us the html of the link and how it is generated, also show us your route table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your Comments!!                                 The  Get Method is as Below                                                                        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Hm, how to remove id from your view? Simply. Just remove the declaration of it on View. But is that really what you want?

You will need Id, for update scenarios, for example. So if you really want to remove the Id you should do it on you model, so:

```
product.ProductId = null;
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Actuvally I need to exclude the ID From Creation Page because it's a Primary Key. Sory if i did any wrong in my question. Thanks a lot for consuming your time.

Comment: So was my answer helpful then?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to your model property. This will prevfent it from being dispayed in the front end.

```
 [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```